# Test automation approach for application with vue.js overlay

Tags: vue.js, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to capture if there are any ISE when clicking on any buttons, links, tabs using selenium with java..However, I realized that the vue.js overlay is making it difficult to directly capture from the frontend. Anyone facing a similar issue and how did you overcome this? I do see 500 error messages on the Network tab (devs tool). Appreciate your help.

Comment: Vue.js does not come with a overlay or anything. Probably the site you are testing uses some kind of library. I would advice talking to the creators of the site you are testing, they should know what issues you encounter.

Comment: Can you provide URL and your code including stacktrace?

Comment: sorry I can't share the url..Any other way me to find you a clue? Also I was checked with devs involved in the designing and as per them network tab is the only option.